Getting build error in rollup-plugin-postcss on windows machine
stack trace:
[!] (plugin postcss) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'modules')
at getExtracted (C:\Work\Solutions\RFC\react-frost-components\node_modules\rollup-plugin-postcss\dist\index.js:931:49)
at C:\Work\Solutions\RFC\react-frost-components\node_modules\rollup-plugin-postcss\dist\index.js:975:29
at Generator.next ()
at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Work\Solutions\RFC\react-frost-components\node_modules\rollup-plugin-postcss\dist\index.js:29:24)
at _next (C:\Work\Solutions\RFC\react-frost-components\node_modules\rollup-plugin-postcss\dist\index.js:51:9)
at C:\Work\Solutions\RFC\react-frost-components\node_modules\rollup-plugin-postcss\dist\index.js:58:7
at new Promise ()
at C:\Work\Solutions\RFC\react-frost-components\node_modules\rollup-plugin-postcss\dist\index.js:47:12
at Object.generateBundle (C:\Work\Solutions\RFC\react-frost-components\node_modules\rollup-plugin-postcss\dist\index.js:1018:9)
at C:\Work\Solutions\RFC\react-frost-components\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:989:40
make: *** [Makefile:43: build] Error 1
rollup config file:
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import jsonPlugin from '@rollup/plugin-json'
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
import {createRequire} from 'module'
import path from 'node:path'
// import eslint from '@rollup/plugin-eslint';
import {fileURLToPath} from 'node:url'
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import svgSprites from 'rollup-plugin-svg-sprites'
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url)

const packageJson = require('./package.json')
const glob = require('glob')
const plugins = [
  postcss({
    extract: 'styles.css',
    minimize: true,
    inject: false,
    sourceMap: true,
    extension: ['.scss', '.css'],
    use: ['sass']
  }),
  external(),
  resolve({browser: true, extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.css', '.scss', '.sass']}),
  babel({
    exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/preset-react'],
    babelHelpers: 'runtime'
  }),
  commonjs(),
  typescript({tsconfig: './tsconfig.json'}),
  svgSprites({
    symbolId: (path, query) => {
      return `frost-${path.split('/').pop().replace('.svg', '')}`
    }
  }),
  jsonPlugin()
  // eslint({
  //     exclude: ['*.svg', '*.json', '*.scss']
  // })
]

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: 'cjs',
        sourcemap: true,
        name: 'react-frost-components'
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
        name: 'react-frost-components'
      }
    ],
    plugins,
    external: ['lodash', 'immer', 'tslib', /node_modules/]
  },
  {
    input: Object.fromEntries(
      glob.sync('src/**/!(*.d).[jt]s*').map(file => [
        path.relative(
          'src',
          file.slice(0, file.length - path.extname(file).length)
        ),
        fileURLToPath(new URL(file, import.meta.url))
      ])
    ),
    output: {
      format: 'es',
      dir: 'lib'
    },
    plugins,
    external: ['lodash', 'immer', 'tslib', /node_modules/]
  }
]


I was expecting this to build. This is working on my colleagues' machines (iMac) but not working on Windows.

I had the same issue, please make sure to change '\' to '/' in all of your inputs (after export default), e.g. use replace(/\+/g, '/').
